# Remove rows based on decimal places in column

Tags: r

I have a date frame that looks something like this:

```
     A  B      C   D

     1  1.0    2   4 

     2  3.1    2   3

     3  4.01   3   3

     4  5.00   4   5

     5  2.003  3   9
```

I want to delete rows where column B has numeric values other than 0 after the decimal. In the example above, this will leave me with rows 1 and 4. How do I go about this?

Comment: Try: `x[x$B == round(x$B),]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`:

```
df[as.integer(df$B) == as.numeric(df$B),]
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex solution in `base R`:

```
df[-which(grepl("\\.[0-9]*[1-9]$", df$B)),]
  A   B C
2 2   1 2
5 5 357 3
```

A regex solution in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(!grepl("\\.[0-9]*[1-9]$", B))
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = 1:5,
  B = c(1.2, 1.0, 1.00004, 2.806, 357.0),
  C = c(2,2,3,4,3)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `subset` like below

```
subset(df, B == floor(B))
subset(df, B == ceiling(B))
subset(df, B == round(B))
subset(df, B == trunc(B))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use

```
subset(df, B == as.integer(B))
```